# JSF 2.0 Validator Wrapping

Tags: jsf

I ran into a problem when I tried to apply a custom validator to an input field:

I want to use a custom validator that is generated by a bean and bound to a f:validator tag:

```
<f:validator binding="#{bean.myValidator}">
```

The corresponding bean method looks like this:

```
public Validator getMyValidator(){
  return new Validator(){...};
}
```

If I'm using the tag inside an input tag like this:

```
<h:input value="...">
  <f:validator binding="#{bean.myValidator}" />
</h:input>
```

then everything works as expected.

However, if I'm using the tags the other way around like this:

```
<f:validator binding="#{bean.myValidator}">
  <h:input value="...">
</f:validator>
```

then I get a ServletException ("validatorID is null").

*What is the reason for this Exception?*

Also, I don't understand the corresponding [f:validator tag spec](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/f/validator.html):

> If this element is nested within a UIComponent tag that has other UIComponent children, the validator will be automatically added to all the child components as well as this one.

I guess my f:validator tag is nested within f:view, correct?
What does "to all the child components" mean? Whose child components?

Answer (score 1):

> *What is the reason for this Exception?*

I'm not sure. Both Mojarra 2.1.3 and MyFaces 2.1.1 exposes the same problem. It works when the validator is a standalone `@FacesValidator("myValidator")` class which is been specified by `<f:validator validatorId="myValidator">`.  The [spec](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr314/index.html) nor the [vdl](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/) describes this behaviour. You might want to post an [issue report](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES_SPEC_PUBLIC) to the JSF spec guys to clarify this more in the spec or vdl.

---

> *Also, I don't understand the corresponding f:validator tag spec:*
>
> If this element is nested within a UIComponent tag that has other UIComponent children, the validator will be automatically added to all the child components as well as this one.
>
> *I guess my f:validator tag is nested within f:view, correct? What does "to all the child components" mean? Whose child components?*

It's just a terrible wording of whatever you're trying to achieve is just supported: wrapping a common validator over a set of components. You might want to ask the JSF spec guys to clarify this more as well.